# Missing artifact de.jetwick:snacktory:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven

I am trying to use `snacktory` thus I have the following in my `pom.xml` file:

```
    <!-- ... -->

    <dependencies>

        <!-- ... -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jetwick</groupId>
            <artifactId>snacktory</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>snacktory_snapshots</id>
            <url>https://github.com/karussell/mvnrepo/tree/master/snapshots/de/jetwick/snacktory/</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

</project>
```

However, I am getting

```
Missing artifact de.jetwick:snacktory:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

in Eclipse from the Maven build. I've tried, as in another question stated `1.2` and `1.3` as well but the result is the same.

Why am I not able to get this dependency?

Comment: the repository url needs to be verified by you.

Answer (score 1):

If you look on their github repository (used as a maven repository), they provide the repository url to use : https://github.com/karussell/mvnrepo

## Change the repository to:

```
<repository>
  <id>snacktory_snapshots</id>
  <url>https://github.com/karussell/mvnrepo/raw/master/snapshots</url>
</repository>
```

## Use the release instead

I would advise you to use their release version instead:

```
<repository>
  <id>snacktory_releases</id>
  <url>https://github.com/karussell/mvnrepo/raw/master/releases</url>
</repository>
```

with the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.jetwick</groupId>
    <artifactId>snacktory</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```